# How do I integrate SwiftyPing into my project?

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

I am quite new to Swift and test a little to get better. Unfortunately I don't know how to integrate SwiftyPing https://github.com/samiyr/SwiftyPing into my project.
Also the example code cannot be executed in my app.
I have dragged the SwiftyPing.swift file into my project. 
My project only consists of a tab bar controller with two storyboards but no functionality yet.
When I include the example code in my ViewController.swift file I get two errors: 
"Cannot use optional chaining on non-optional value of type 'SwiftyPing'" "Call can throw, but errors cannot be thrown out of a global variable initializer".

Comment: Hi! How did you "include the example code" in your project? Can you share a few lines to illustrate what you are trying to do? According to the compiler errors you're getting, you're trying to use optional chaining (i.e. the `?` notation) on a `SwiftyPing` instance that is declared non-optional, and you somewhere have a `try` without a corresponding `catch` statement.

Comment: I really just have a normal standard ViewController.swift file without any adjustments and add the example code. Easier asked, where can I insert the sample code just to see if and how it works?

Comment: If you look at the SwiftyPing repository you linked in the question, inside the `SwiftyPingTest` directory, you find a `SwiftyPingTest.xcodeproj` project that can be opened in Xcode. You can build and run that to execute their example and see how it works.